# React-Native Updating Listview Data Source from Different File

Tags: listview, react-native, datasource

I have a listview in my A class, which is rendered like this:

```
<ListView
    style = {Styles.itemList}
    dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow = {(data) => <MyItem {...data} />}
/>
```

I separate my Item to another file since the list item is quite complicated, like this:

```
const MyItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={Styles.container}>
            ....
            <Text>{props.firstElement}</Text>
            ....
        </View>
    );
}
```

I have a TouchableHighlight (Button) component inside MyItem component, where once it presses, then I have to change my listview's data source (which is in my A class), how to trigger or call setState for this data source from MyItem (which is in different class).

Is there any solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an callback function, just pass the function you have create on the A class like `renderRow = {(data) => <MyItem callback={this.MyChangeList} {...data} />}`.
Them on your MyItem class you can call it using `this.props.callback()`.